# Node.js (V8) Map initial capacity

Tags: node.js, dictionary

In Node.js we have the possibility to use the `Map` object

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
```

and we can create a `Map` instance in this way

```
const m = new Map();
```

is there also the possibility to define the **INITIAL CAPACITY** of my Map?

I need to insert about 1.000.000 of items inside the Map, so I don't want to rehash the table 20 times every time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way (currently) to set the initial capacity of a `Map` object.
However, the first (and only) argument for a `Map` is an iterable of length N, which will force the newly created `Map` to `set` them internally. So you can "bypass" this by passing such argument.

But this means you'll have to create it first, thus you "spend" the memory you wanted to "save" on allocating the initial value ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Here's an example of a "premade" `Map` of length 100:

```js
new Map([...Array(100)].map((v,i)=>[i, i])) // creates a map of 0=>0, 1=1, ...
```

You can look at the source for `Map` in `V8` here:

- Header: [map.h](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/map.h)
- Implementation: [map.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/objects/map.cc)